# Windows Forms, функция Button Click, try catch

Tags: c++-cli

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    try{
        Flights f;
        string buffer = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(textBox1 -> Text);
        if(isNumber(buffer, true)){
            f.setNum(atoi(buffer.c_str()));
        }
        else{
            MessageBox::Show("не яяется числом", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Error);
            throw;
        }
        buffer = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(textBox2 -> Text);
        if(isNumber(buffer, true) ){
            f.setDays(atoi(buffer.c_str()));
        }
        else{
            MessageBox::Show("не ялвяется числом", "Ошибка1", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Error);
            throw;
        }
        buffer = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(textBox3 -> Text);
        vector<string> v;
        splitString(buffer, v);
        if(v.size() != f.getDays()) {
            MessageBox::Show("Количество не совпадает", "Ошибка2", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Error);
            throw;
        }
        double p;
        for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++){
            if(isNumber(v[i], false)){
                istringstream is(v[i]);
                is >> p;
                f.put(p, i);
            }
            else {
                MessageBox::Show("не является числом", "Ошибка3", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Error);
                throw;
            }
        }

        stringstream s;
        s << f.sumNumber();
        MessageBox::Show(gcnew System::String((s.str()).c_str()), "Количество дней когда 0", MessageBoxButtons::OK);
        char buff[126];
        strcpy(buff, f.toString().c_str());
        String^ sk = gcnew System::String(buff);
        label1 -> Text += (sk);
    }catch(...) {
        textBox1 -> Text = "";
        textBox2 -> Text = "";
        textBox3 -> Text = "";
    }
}
```

Как сделать что-бы при вводе в поле символа (не цифры) программа не завершалась, а продолжала работать. В данный момент она вылетает.

Comment: Зачем вам этот ужас на C++/CLI?

Comment: А как у вас компилируется `throw;` вне блока `catch`, интересно?

Comment: все компилит, и почему не должно?

Comment: Окей, а _что_ за исключение будет брошено в этом случае?

Comment: У МЕНЯ В CATCH ПРОГРАММА ДОЛЖНА ПРОДОЛЖАТЬ  РАБОТАТЬ, А НЕ ВЫЛЕТАТЬ.   КАК ЭТО  СДЕЛАТЬ ?

Comment: Для таких вещей обычно используют finally. Блок catch совсем не для этого.